# What is the difference between $("selector") and $("selector").toArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was reading documentation on `toArray()` here and testing it out in the console. I cannot find the difference between calling `toArray()` on a selector and calling the selector itself.

I got the exact same result both ways, which is an array of DOM elements matching the selector. I even did another test

```
$("element").toArray()[0] === $("element")[0]
```

According to w3schools

> The toArray() method returns the elements matched by the jQuery
>   selector as an array.

However, it looks like just querying the element itself does the exact same thing. And it's a lot easier to write as well.

Does anyone know the difference between these two? If not, I don't understand the purpose of this function.

Comment: `toArray` gives you a pure js array so you can call javascript `Array.prototype` methods on it.

Comment: If you're accessing individual elements in the array then there is no difference (as your own test shows). It's what you do with the array itself (do you call more jQuery on the results?) that matters.

Comment: Try this and you'll immediately see why... `$("div").toArray().hide();`

Comment: In addition, You can inspect both objects using console.log   to see the differences

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take this example from [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

If you do something like `$('img').reverse()`, you will get an error.

If you do something like `$('img').toArray().reverse()` you will get the reversed array of DOM nodes.

This is because if you don't perform the `toArray()` first, you won't have all the cool [Array prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) available to you.

Comment: Well, for the record `typeof` on any JavaScript array will return `object`. There are other Array-like objects out there, such as the `arguments` object given in any function body.